# Stopping expo background location update gives the error "Task 'geofencing' not found for app ID"

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm using React Native with Expo Location.startLocationUpdatesAsync. I have created three functions in the same file, the first two are in my export default App function, with TaskManager defined globally in the file.

```
async startBackgroundUpdate() {
    await Location.startLocationUpdatesAsync(taskName, {
      accuracy: Location.Accuracy.Highest,
      timeInterval: 0,
      distanceInterval: 0,
      forgroundService: {
        notificationTitle: "I'm a notification title",
        notificationBody: "I'm a notification body",
        notificationBody: "#abcdef"
      }
    }); 
}

async stopBackgroundUpdate() {
  await Location.stopLocationUpdatesAsync(taskName)
}

TaskManager.defineTask(taskName, async ({ data, error }) => {
  if (error) {
    return console.log(error)
  }
  if (data) {
    const { locations } = data;
    locationGlobal = locations[0];
    let date = new Date(locationGlobal.timestamp).toISOString().slice(-13, -5)
    // App.setLocation(location)
    console.log("Task has been running "+ count +" time(s). With data: "+data);
    console.log(locationGlobal);
    console.log(count++);
    console.log(date)
  }
});
```

I also have a global variable that holds the taskName

```
const taskName = 'geofencing'
```

The stop and start background location functions are hooked up to a button. I can start the background location fine, but when I try and stop it I get the error

```
Task 'geofencing' not found for app ID '@anonymous/track-it-fecc322d-0ade-4239-8bd1-fdcb47b0397e'.
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\NativeModules.js:104:55 in <unknown>
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:414:4 in __invokeCallback
- ... 4 more stack frames from framework internals
```

I am new to this and I think I am missing a piece of the puzzle. I can see the taskName and create the task from inside my App function but at the same level I can't reference it to stop it, any ideas?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?